# How do I override the read timeout on the default Spring Test TestRestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot Starter Test in my unit tests for a Rest Service. When I use the provided (i.e. autowired) TestRestTemplate, it seems to default to a readTimeout of around 10 seconds), even though the docs imply that it sets  a virtually infinite timeout. This is ok for when the tests run normally, but if the tests fail and I want to get in with the debugger to see what the issue is, I timeout long before being able to see anything that's going on.

So I assumed that I could just create and inject a new RestTemplateBuilder into my app, which the TestRestTemplate would use. This worked for setting the timeout, but my application also has a custom MessageConverter, which was properly loaded in the injected TestRestTemplate, but not in my overridden RestTemplateBuilder.

According to various searches of the net, the RestTemplateBuilder was supposed to use a JVM flag called sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout, but setting this had exactly no effect.

So my question is this: What is the easiest way to set the readTimeout for requests created by the default TestRestTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout should not matter at all. When using a debugger, you should be adding a breakpoint on the line or after the line. Unless you went into the RequestFactory to add your breakpoint, it is not going to affect the timeout.

```
testRestTemplate.getForEntity("<path-to-resources>", SomeObject.class); // Breakpoint here
someOtherCode.doSomething();    // Or breakpoint here
```

One thing you can check out with your debugger is the readTimeout property.

```
testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().getRequestFactory().readTimeout
```